# Controller with annotation type. How to implement onsubmit and select input

Tags: java, spring, select, controller, annotations

help me please. I want to do controller which passes data to my jsp and this jsp uses this data to make select input with options.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add/city", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView selectCountry(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("addcity");
        model.addObject("countries", coserv.getAllCountries());
        return model;
    }
```

My addcity.jsp

```
    <form:form method="post">


        Name of City<br />
        <form:input path="name" /><br /><br />

        Select Country:<br />
        <form:select path="id_country">
        <c:forEach items="${countries}" var ="country">
        <form:option value="${country.id}">${country.name}</form:option>
        </c:forEach>



</form:select><br />
```

I want that my controller takes user's input and writes it to in column name(field of City entity) and shows select menu with  my countries. How to do this without SimpleFormController. And my second question how to do onSubmit method without SMC and can we have 2 onSubmit methods which places in one page? Please explain me where we write this page, class (to take path=name), and success page (onSubmit method)? Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

SimpleFormController has been deprecated in Spring 3. You can simply annotate any class with `@Controller` in Spring 3

```
@Controller
public class AddCityController {
```

You also need to ask user for the city name

```
Enter city name: <input type="text" name="cityName">
```

And bind this into your handler method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add/city", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addCity(@RequestParam("cityName") String cityName, Model model) {
  // persist city using data layer
  ...
  return "addCitySuccess";
}
```

Consider also [using form backing bean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) to bind the whole form field into a pojo.